# Why I get the C2059 error?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

MS Visual Studio 2012 (cl.exe command line compiler). Why I get an error (read the comment)?

```
// C89
#include<ctype.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(void){
    long int i;
    long int n = 1000;
    clock_t cur_time1 = clock();
    clock_t cur_time2;
    long double secs;   
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i);
    cur_time2 = clock();
    // Here I get an error C2059
    secs = long double(cur_time2 - cur_time1)/long double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);  
    printf("For the thousand: %lf sec.\nFor the billion: %lf sec.\n", 
        secs, secs * 1000000);
    getchar();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the description of this error? We can't remember all error codes..

Comment: @Kiril Kirov http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8xe60cf.aspx

Comment: please Try `secs = (long double)((cur_time2 - cur_time1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);` in place of `secs = long double(cur_time2 - cur_time1)/long double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);`

Comment: Oh thank you. It works: `secs = (long double)((long double)(cur_time2 - cur_time1)/(long double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
secs = long double(cur_time2 - cur_time1)/long double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

This is the line generating the error, the correct usage of type cast is:

```
secs = (long double)(cur_time2 - cur_time1)/(long double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```